# Android . Google Play In app purchase

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I want to create a section in my app for removing ads . But I have a question . What shall I write in my code instead of developerPayload ?

```
ArrayList skuList = new ArrayList();
    skuList.add(inappid);
    Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
    querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
    Bundle skuDetails;
    try {
        skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(),
                "inapp", querySkus);

        int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
        if (response == 0) {

            ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails
                    .getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

            for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                String sku = object.getString("productId");
                String price = object.getString("price");
                if (sku.equals(inappid)) {
                    System.out.println("price " + price);
                    Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService
                            .getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku,
                                    "inapp",
                                    "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle
                            .getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
                    startIntentSenderForResult(
                            pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001,
                            new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0),
                            Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the part of code . I want to know what shall I write instead of bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ ?

Comment: you can put whatever you want there `developerPayload - optional argument to be sent back with the purchase information`

Comment: ok thank you) but I am getting an error now , the version of the application is not configured for billing ...

Comment: look here http://cs617829.vk.me/v617829733/19ce4/d3axZpjPI4Q.jpg

Comment: you need to sign your app for release then upload it to the play store in either the alpha or beta channel to test it. It is one of the frustrating things about using in-app billing is that you cant really debug stuff and have to put in a lot of logging to test

Comment: is there any tutorial for it?. I have uploaded and published it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Comment: I have to make Alfa or beta testing? or I can simply publish app?

Comment: well you can certainly publish it but then anyone can download the app